# Display fields in three columns twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns, paragraphs

I have an array like below

```
us_states = [('AL', 'Alabama'),('AK', 'Alaska'),('AZ', 'Arizona'),('AR', 'Arkansas')('CA', 'California'),('CO', 'Colorado'),('CT', 'Connecticut'),('DE', 'Delaware'),.... until 50 us states]
```

So based on this list/array i am generating the html fields in a `p` as below

```
{% for state in us_states %}
   <p>
     <input id="{{state.0}}" type="checkbox" name="{{state.0}}"/>   
     <span style="padding-left:5px;">{{state.1}}</span>
     <input id="id_{{state.1}}" type="text" name="{{state.0}}" value="0.0">
   </p>
{% endfor %}
```

So from the above html code, i can able to generate the `checkbox, input field` according the `length of array` , i mean for example i have 50 us states in the list/array, so 50 `p elements` with checkbox, span, input elements are generated succesfully

But the problem is all the fields are generating in a single page line by line,
but what i want is i want to divide them in to `three columns` (like 20, 15, 15 what ever), so that the UI looks good right ?

So i am really confused on how to achieve this with twitter bootstrap ? 
So can anyone please let me know, on how to arrange the 50 p elements that are generated from the list in to there columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to manually create 3 column divs and make three loops that go through 1-20, 21-35, 36-50.

Depending on your templating engine (twig? underscore? ejs?), it should look like this algorithm:

```
<div class="column">
    {% for (i=1; i<20; i++) { %}
        <p>
          ...
          {{ states[i].0 }} - {{ states[i].1 }}
          ...
        </p>
    {% } %}
</div>
<div class="column">
    {% for (i=21; i<35; i++) { %}
        <p>
          ...
          {{ states[i].0 }} - {{ states[i].1 }}
          ...
        </p>
    {% } %}
</div>
<div class="column">
    {% for (i=36; i<50; i++) { %}
        <p>
          ...
          {{ states[i].0 }} - {{ states[i].1 }}
          ...
        </p>
    {% } %}
</div>
```

Using bootstrap you should perhaps use a `span4` instead of the `column` class in my case

Alternatively, a ninja could put all three loops into a single nested loops, the outer loop just changes the values that `i` iterates through.

Comment: Actually i am using django(Python) templating system to lop through the list whic i am getting from my view

Comment: Well i'm sure you could check how simple `for` loops are implemented in that templating engine.